# What is the simplest method for exporting figures from TikzEdt to TeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, editors, eps

What is the simplest method for saving/exporting a figure drawed by TikzEdt to TeX?

Specially, I wonder that how to save/export a figure from TikzEdt to `.eps` format?

*Note: I read a lof topic about this in here. But I still can't do. Could you explain for a beginner?*

Comment: the whole point of tikzedit is to create tikz, which is tex code, so you can just `\input` it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TikzEdt already creates a code that you can (from "File" menu) "Save As..." `yourfile.tex` (or `yourfile.tikz`) and then you can directly input in your main file with `\input{yourfile.tex}`. In this case, check to have in the preamble of your main file all the packages and tikzlibraries that you have in "Code predended" in "Settings --> Settings --> Compiler".

Otherwise, you can choose "Save Pdf As..." to save `yourfile.pdf` or "Export File As...", the available formats are:

[image]

```
Graphics Interchange Format (*.gif)
Extended Meta File (*.emf)
Windows Meta File (*.wmf)
Html File (*.html)
Scalable Vector Graphics (*.svg)
```

(unfortunately, `.eps` is not available) and then you can include in your main file with `\includegraphics{yourfile.yourformat}` of `graphics` package.

Comment: Thank you very much @CarLatex.  I saw some ways to transform .Eps format from TikzEdt in this site. I am trying to perform them, but I can' t. Can you summarize it, if you know?

Comment: @captain23 You're welcome! I think the simplest thing to do is to install ImageMagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php and convert the `.pdf` directly with the command: `convert yourfile.pdf yourfile.eps` (from command prompt if you are using Windows or the correspondent one if you are using another OS).